# Rake says "Don't know how to build task X", but "rake -T" lists it anyway - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a new OS X El Capitan setup with Ruby 2.2 (Macports), Rails 4.2.4 and Bundler for an existing app. Among a lot of other gems, this app uses `parallel_tests` to make good use of my 8-core machine. `rake -T` lists all the parallel test and spec tasks fine and in the past I could execute them. But when I do this now, after the upgrade, I just get

```
$ /opt/local/bin/rake parallel:prepare --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'parallel:prepare'
/opt/local/lib/ruby2.2/2.2.0/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/opt/local/lib/ruby2.2/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
```

What can cause a task to be listed in `rake -T`, but not be found when I try to execute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the reason was that I had put the gem in question inside a group `:test` in my Gemfile. Apparently this caused the problem, removing it from the group and making it available globally resolved the problem (after calling `bundle` again).

I don't know whether this is a generic solution, however.